# Does the Google Play Developer Console display APK uploads in UTC or local time?

Tags: android, apk, google-play, google-play-services

I'm attempting to determine the exact date of an APK upload on the Google Play developer console and correlate that to a specific commit in my git logs but there seems to a date discrepancy. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be the time of Mountain View (Google head office) UTC-08:00

Comment: Thanks, I validated this by uploading a draft as well - bad move on Google's part.